# Evaluating the geocode precision of US addresses

Tags: address

I am evaluating various services that take an address in the United States as an input and returns latitude and longitude of the address. Is there a way I can evaluate which service returns the most accurate coordinates?

For example:

Input: 350 Fifth Avenue New York, NY 10118

Output:

Service a: 40.74838, -73.98468

Service b: 40.7483, -73.9853

Is there a way to evaluate which service returned a LAT/LONG closest to the rooftop of the address without manually looking at each set of coordinates on a map?

Comment: I expect the answer to be no, you can't do it without inspection. In order to do it programmatically or automatically there would need to be a gold standard, available as a service, to compare against. To the best of my knowledge that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo and Google have a quality in the  geocoded response:

Google Geocoder (API JSON)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=350%20Fifth%20Avenue%20New%20York,%20NY%2010118&sensor=false

Result Quality Match is 'Rooftop'

```
{

    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Empire State Building",
                    "short_name": "ESB",
                    "types": [
                        "premise"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "350",
                    "short_name": "350",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "5th Avenue",
                    "short_name": "5th Ave",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Midtown",
                    "short_name": "Midtown",
                    "types": [
                        "neighborhood",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Manhattan",
                    "short_name": "Manhattan",
                    "types": [
                        "sublocality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "New York",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "New York",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "NY",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "10118",
                    "short_name": "10118",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Empire State Building, 350 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10118, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.7489544,
                        "lng": -73.9848178
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.7479245,
                        "lng": -73.9865073
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40.74843329999999,
                    "lng": -73.9856556
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.7497884302915,
                        "lng": -73.98431356970849
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.7470904697085,
                        "lng": -73.98701153029151
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": [
                "premise"
            ]
        },
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "350",
                    "short_name": "350",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "5th Avenue",
                    "short_name": "5th Ave",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Midtown",
                    "short_name": "Midtown",
                    "types": [
                        "neighborhood",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Manhattan",
                    "short_name": "Manhattan",
                    "types": [
                        "sublocality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "New York",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "New York",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "New York",
                    "short_name": "NY",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "10118",
                    "short_name": "10118",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "350 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10118, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40.748298,
                    "lng": -73.9855408
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.74964698029149,
                        "lng": -73.98419181970849
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.7469490197085,
                        "lng": -73.9868897802915
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"

}
```

Yahoo result

```
40.748362,-73.984619,USA,350 Fifth Avenue New York, NY 10118,Yahoo Geocoder,Quality 87 Address match with street match
```